# how can one test if a remote Rest WS is alive?

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, rest, browser

I write corrective actions for our cutomers (IT people) and one of the steps I'd like to provide them is to easily check if some Remote REST service is up and running.

What is the easiest way to reach this ALIVE() logic?

Can they open web browser and do something like

```
Http://<Server>:<Port>
```

- or something?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Good solution will be simple console application that will request your rest service with control request and check response of this request.

**Update:**
If you cannot create this console application, you can give instruction to your customers:

1. Open browser;
2. Request Http://:
3. It should response control response.

Comment: thanks, if there are not dev resources for this? is there out of the box simple action can be taken? for example - is it fair to say that if I ping the hostname and port the service is responsive?

Comment: In this case you can give instruction: open browser, call Http://<Server>:<Port> and it responses control response.